# Shade a ListLinePlot of many series with their deviations

Tags: plotting, filling

Consider a single list of data `avg = {.5, .6, .5,...}` with corresponding standard deviations `dev = {.1, .2, .2, ...}`.

I use some pretty verbose code...

```
ListLinePlot[
    {avg, avg + dev, avg - dev},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, None, None},
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}
]
```

to create a plot like this

[image: a single series plot]

which shows the data (the blue line) and shades the region spanned by 2x standard deviations of each datum (like a continuous error bar).

There are clearly problems with this method, chiefly that I had to manually specify the colour palette (`Blue` in `PlotStyle`).

This becomes a pain when I want to present multiple series. Imagine I had list-of-lists `avgs = {{.5, ...}, {.6, ...}}` and similarly structured standard deviations `devs`. To plot the first 3 of my series, I can do

```
ListLinePlot[
    {
        avgs[[1]], avgs[[1]] + devs[[1]], avgs[[1]] - devs[[1]],
        avgs[[2]], avgs[[2]] + devs[[2]], avgs[[2]] - devs[[2]],
        avgs[[3]], avgs[[3]] + devs[[3]], avgs[[3]] - devs[[3]]
    },
    PlotStyle -> {
        Blue, None, None, 
        Orange, None, None,
        Red, None, None
    },
    Filling -> {
        1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3},
        4 -> {5}, 4 -> {6},
        7 -> {8}, 7 -> {9}
     }
]
```

to produce

[image: multi series plot]

I now need to plot about 30 series like this!

While it's easy (albeit seemingly unnecessary) to create the first and third arguments to `ListLinePlot` programmatically, constructing `PlotStyle` in this way is painful for a general number of series.

So; is there a less-crude way to go about this?
Could I otherwise get some help in automating `PlotStyle` to use/wrap-around a colour palette?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** Wrapping all in a function:

```
ClearAll[deviationslLLP]
deviationslLLP[ave_, dev_, opts: OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{fill = 
  Join @@ (Thread[Range[Length@ave] -> 
   List/@(Length[ave] # + Range[Length@ave])]& /@ {1, 2}), 
  apd = Style[#, Opacity[0]] & /@ (ave + dev), 
  amd = Style[#, Opacity[0]] & /@ (ave - dev)},
 ListLinePlot[Join @@ {ave, apd, amd}, Filling -> fill, opts]]
```

**Examples:**

```
dt = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, .05], {10, 50}];
averages = Mean[# dt] & /@ Range[10];
sdevs = StandardDeviation[# dt] & /@ Range[10];

deviationslLLP[averages, sdevs, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotLegends -> RandomWord["Noun", 10]]]
```

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

You can wrap `ave - dev` and `ave + dev` pieces of your data with `Style[#, Opacity[0]]&` to avoid using `PlotStyle`:

```
dt = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, .1], {10, 50}];
averages = Mean[# dt] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
sdevs = StandardDeviation[# dt] & /@ {1, 2, 3};
aplussd = Style[#, Opacity[0]]&/@(averages + sdevs);
aminussd = Style[#, Opacity[0]]&/@(averages - sdevs);
fillings[n_] := Join @@ (Thread[Range[n] -> List/@(n # + Range[n])]& /@ {1, 2});

ListLinePlot[Join@@{averages, aplussd, aminussd}, Filling -> fillings[Length @ averages]]
```

[image]

If you wish yo use `PlotStyle` you can to specify three colors, say, `PlotStyle->{Red, Green,Purple}]` to get

[image]

Or `PlotStyle->{Automatic, Green,Purple}]` to get

[image]

Use `NormalDistribution[1, .05]`  instead of `NormalDistribution[1, .1]` and `Range[10]` instead of `{1,2,3}` to get

[image]

Add the option `PlotStyle -> 63` to get

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for (though I've had a hard time controlling evaluation order when wrapping this in a function)

Comment: @AntiEarth, please see the update.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use a function like `makePlot` in `MapThread`:

```
makePlot = Function[{avg, dev, col},
             ListLinePlot[{avg, avg - dev, avg + dev},
               PlotStyle -> {col, None, None}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}]];

plots = MapThread[makePlot, {avgs, devs, {Blue, Orange, Red}}];

Show[plots]
```

Comment: Automating the args is the easy part; I'm looking for help in not having to explicitly specify a fixed-length colour palette (also using `Show` introduces new problems; I'd prefer to avoid it)

Answer (score 3):

I have the sense that this has been answered before, but a quick look couldn't find it, so here's my quick take on it:

```
ClearAll[varianceListPlot];
Options[varianceListPlot] =
  Options[ListLinePlot];
varianceListPlot[
    domMainLowHigh :
     {
      Repeated[
       {
        {__?NumericQ},
        {__?NumericQ},
        {__?NumericQ},
        {__?NumericQ}
        }
       ]
      },
    ops : OptionsPattern[]
    ] /; Length[DeleteDuplicates[Map[Length, domMainLowHigh, {2}]]] ==
     1 :=
  With[
   {
    plots =
     Join @@
      Map[
       With[{dom = #[[1]]},
         Map[
          Thread[{dom, #}] &, 
          {#[[2]], #[[2]] + #[[3]], #[[2]] - #[[4]]}
          ]
         ] &,
       domMainLowHigh
       ],
    ps = Replace[OptionValue[PlotStyle], Automatic :> ColorData[97]]
    },
   ListLinePlot[
    plots,
    PlotStyle ->
     Table[
      If[Mod[i, 3] == 1, 
       If[ListQ@ps, 
        ps[[Mod[Floor[i/3] + 1, Length@ps, 1]]],
        Replace[ps[Floor[i/3] + 1], _ps :> ps]
        ],
       None
       ],
      {i, Length@plots}
      ],
    ops,
    Filling ->
     Flatten@
      Table[
       {
        i -> {i + 1},
        i -> {i + 2}
        },
       {i, 1, Length@plots, 3}
       ]
    ]
   ];
varianceListPlot[
   dataDevs : 
    Repeated[{{_?NumericQ, _?
        NumericQ, {Repeated[_?NumericQ, 2]}}, ___}],
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  varianceListPlot[
   {#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2]], #[[All, 3, 1]], #[[All, 3, 2]]} & /@ 
    dataDevs,
   ops
   ];
varianceListPlot[
   dd :
    {
     {__?NumericQ},
     {__?NumericQ},
     {__?NumericQ},
     {__?NumericQ}
     },
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  varianceListPlot[{dd}, ops];
varianceListPlot[
  dataDevs : {{_?NumericQ, _?
      NumericQ, {Repeated[_?NumericQ, 2]}}, ___}, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 varianceListPlot[{dataDevs}, ops]
```

I provided a two syntaxes; either you pass the domain, main plot, upper variance, and lower variance as a 4-tuple for each data set or you can do it point-wise as `{x, y, {above, below}}` and it'll unwrap to the prior syntax.

```
varianceListPlot[
 {
  {
   dom,
   Sin[dom],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom]
   },
  {
   dom,
   Cos[dom],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom]
   },
  {
   dom,
   3*Cos[dom/π],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom],
   ConstantArray[1, Length@dom]
   }
  }
 ]
```

[image: blahblah]